# Use python keywords like dict, list, type inside robot framework

Tags: testing, robotframework

```
a  = {}
if type(a) == dict:
    #read using dictionary keys.
else:
    #treat it as a list
```

How can one migrate the python code to robot framework. I tried this,

```
${type_obj}=     Evaluate   type(${a})
${type_bool}=    Evaluate   ${type_obj} == dict 
Run Keyword If   ${type_bool}==1    DictHandler
Run Keyword If   ${type_bool}==0    ListHandler
```

But it just broke with a syntax error as,

```
Evaluating expression '<type 'dict'> == dict' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

The issue is, robot treats python's `dict` keyword as a string. So, how can i check a variable's type inside robot?

Answer (score 0):

```
${type_obj}=    Evaluate    type(${a})
Run Keyword If    'dict' in '${type_obj}'    DictHandler
...    ELSE    ListHandler
```